# Get array of posts from the current archive page loop

Tags: wp-query, loop

Classic WordPress loop (for example in `archive.php`) looks like this:

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;
endif;
```

I want to get an array of post objects on archive page without having to do this:

```
$my_posts = array();
while ( have_posts() ) {
  the_post();
  $my_posts[] = $post;
}

// $my_posts is array of post objects
```

Is there any simpler method to get it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That’s pretty easy. All you need is this:

```
global $wp_query;
$my_posts = $wp_query->posts;
```